# Increasing image margin based on a label value html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, margin

I have an image that is at the bottom of the screen and I would like to increase its margins (move it towards the top) based on the value of a label.

```
<img src="flag.png"
style=" margin-left:50%;
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:50%;
        bottom:0px;
        ">
<label id="countdown" > countdown: </label>
```

Label id="countdown" is updated frequently.

Essentially, is it possible to move the image up (increase the value of "bottom:0;") based on the value of the id="countdown"?

Comment: yes, you need a JS to keep checking the value of countdown each time it changes... but first of all, paste your JS here, show what you've attempted

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how the value of the label is changed. 
It might be easier to update the flag styling at the same time you update the label content.

Here's an example to get you started:
https://jsfiddle.net/fztkjb89/

```
$(function() {
  var initialCountDown = 100;
  var countDown = initialCountDown;


  setInterval(function(){
    // update label 
    $('#counter').text(countDown); 

    // update image style
    $('img').css('bottom', initialCountDown-countDown);

    // progress countdown
    countDown--;

    // reset counter
    if (countDown == 0){
      countDown = initialCountDown;
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

If this is not an option, check out my other answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I am after changing the css by reading the value of the label.

Comment: In that case, binding to "DOMSubtreeModified" should work. See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated that you MUST get the value from the label, here's a way to do it:

```js
$(function(){
  $('label').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
   var labelText = $('label').html();
    // use regex to get the number from the label string
    var matches = labelText.match(/\d+$/);
    // event fires with empty text and new contents
    // only update the flag when we have labelText and a valid number
    if(labelText && matches[0]){
       var countDownNumber = parseInt(matches[0]);
        // I use 100 - countdown here, but
        // you would propably have some calculation to determine the height of your flag here.
        $('.flag').css('bottom', 100-countDownNumber)
    }
  });
  
  
  // separate code to update the label
  var i = 100;
  setInterval(function(){ 
   $('label').html('countdown: '+i);
    i--;
    if(i === 0){
     i= 100;
    }
  }, 100);
  
})
```

```css
.flag{
  width: 30px;
  margin-left:50%;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:50%;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="flag" src="http://www.thedayibecameapirate.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Flag3.png">

<label id="countdown" > countdown: <span id="counter"></span></label>
```